# Can I squash commits in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I have a pair of commits that should really be just one. If I was using git, I would use:

```
git rebase -i <some-commit-before>
```

and then squash them.

Can I do that in mercurial? If so, how?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using mercurial without any extensions by [Concatenating Changesets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConcatenatingChangesets).

Alternately if you want to use an extension you could use:

- The [Collapse Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CollapseExtension)
- The [Rebase Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) or
- The [Histedit Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension)

Comment: Yeah, I fished that answer out of the dupe questions I liked to in my comment on the general question.  I think it's your answer on that one.

Comment: Collapse extension was easy to install and very easy to use, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: A little side note: The Histedit extension is distributed with Mercurial 2.3 and later. You just have to enable it.

Comment: In the Concatenating Changesets doc uses abstract concepts of "repos", how to I reference the those?

For example:
hg -R oldrepo export ... produces "abort: repository oldrepo not found!

Comment: Just trying to squash 2 commits. Do I really need a wiki page with 10+ commands or alternative extensions?

Comment: See the comments.  Histedit is now built-in, you just need to enable it (because no default commands will modify history)

Answer (score 49):

My favourite is `hg strip <commit_hash> --keep` command. And then I commit all changes in one commit.

It is the fastest and most comfortable way for me, because I like to do many small commits during my daily work ;)

---

Note 1: `strip` needs a built-in extension `mq` to be enabled.
Note 2: My favourite Git/ Mercurial client (SmartGit/Hg) appends by default `--keep` parameter during `strip`. And what is even more convenient: it provides option called `join commits` :]

Comment: The full command for hg strip is :

`hg strip --keep --rev [rev]`

Where `rev` is the revision number of the first commit you want to squash with the last one

Comment: @NicolasForney Not exactly, `--rev` is optional, full command is `hg strip --keep [rev]`

Comment: Revision is mandatory for me in 3.3.3: `hg help strip` gives `hg strip [-k] [-f] [-n] [-B bookmark] [-r] REV...`, and omitting revision gives me `abort: empty revision set`.

Comment: Using `hg strip` isn't the best idea.  It's not exactly safe.  Try `hg histedit`, maybe even try using the evolve extension.

Comment: Seems the most natural way for git people ;)

Comment: `hg strip --keep -r .` to strip the the current rev.

Answer (score 35):

The [Rebase extension](http://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) worked like a charm. To squash 2 commits:

```
$ hg rebase --dest .~2 --base . --collapse
```

Dot is a shortcut for current revision.

It's even easier when you have a few commits on a branch and want to collapse them all into one:

```
$ hg rebase --dest {destination branch (e.g. master)} --base . --collapse
```

How this works:

[image]

(from http://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension#Collapsing)

Comment: Where did you find the "~2" for two commits?

Comment: It's explained in the revsets topic, see hg help revsets.

Answer (score 15):

> If you are reading this answer, you can forget every other option
>   mentioned in this answer and use the `fold` command from the [evolve
>   extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/).

`evolve` is an extension of mercurial which helps us in having safe mutable history, it's still experimental though. You can use it by cloning it from its [repo](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/evolve) and adding it in your .hgrc like this.

```
[extensions]
evolve = ~/evolve/hgext/evolve.py
```

Assuming that you cloned evolve repo in your home directory. Now you are good to go. You can also look for help by `hg help fold`.

**[Fold Command](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html#example-6-fold-multiple-changesets-together-into-one)**

You tell `fold` to squash/fold a linear chain of commits which is not broken. What fold does is, it creates a new changeset which contains changes from all the changesets and mark all those commits as obsolete. You can have a more deep view into this at [docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html#under-the-hood-fold-multiple-changesets-together-into-one).

Now suppose you have the following history.

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> g
```

You want to squash `e`, `f` and `g`. You can do

```
hg up g
hg fold -r e
```

The result will be

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> h
```

where `h` is the changeset which contains changes from all the three commits `e`, `f` and `g`.

You can also fold changesets from the middle of the history, i.e. not necessarily you have to pick a chain which includes the tip. Suppose you want to fold `b`, `c` and `d`. You can do

```
hg up d
hg fold -r b
hg evolve --all
```

This will result in

```
a -> i -> j
```

where `i` is the folded changeset of `b`, `c`, `d` and `j` is the same changeset as `h`.
[Evolve user guide](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html#evolve-user-guide) is a must read.

Comment: Seems like rebase covers most (maybe all?) use cases of that extension, and certainly the one being asked in this question. The killer feature of that extension is to hide (rather than delete) the revisions you replace, but the `--keep` option of rebase covers this (followed by marking revisions as secret, or using strip on them once you've checked the result). Even moving revisions in between other revisions is possible with a sequence of two rebase commands.

Comment: ... plus, if you're doing something really complicated you can always just clone the local repo first to use as a backup. Considering how rare (hopefully!) that is, it's less effort than learning how to use a totally new extension.

Comment: "NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined"—which means evolve is written in Python 2, which is basically the stone age.

Comment: @NeilG mercurial does not support Python 3 yet.

Comment: I see. In that case, mercurial is in the stone age.

Comment: @NeilG yep, mercurial community is working hard to get py3 support asap.

Answer (score 1):

With Mercurial 4.8 (Nov. 2018, 9 years later), you could consider the new command `hg absorb` (it was an [experimental feature before](https://ahal.ca/blog/2017/mercurial-absorb/)).

See "[Absorbing Commit Changes in Mercurial 4.8](https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2018/11/05/absorbing-commit-changes-in-mercurial-4.8/)"

> The absorb extension will take each change in your working directory, figure out which commits in your series modified that line, and automatically amend the change to that commit.
>   If there is any ambiguity (i.e multiple commits modified the same line), then absorb will simply ignore that change and leave it in your working directory to be resolved manually.
>
> At a technical level, `hg absorb` finds all uncommitted changes and attempts to map each changed line to an unambiguous prior commit.
>   For every change that can be mapped cleanly, the uncommitted changes are absorbed into the appropriate prior commit. Commits impacted by the operation are rebased automatically.
>   If a change cannot be mapped to an unambiguous prior commit, it is left uncommitted and users can fall back to an existing workflow (e.g. using `hg histedit`).
>
> The automatic rewriting logic of `hg absorb` is implemented by following the history of lines: This is fundamentally different from the approach taken by `hg histedit` or `git rebase`, which tend to rely on merge strategies based on the [3-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/6309) to derive a new version of a file given multiple input versions.
>
> This approach combined with the fact that hg absorb skips over changes with an ambiguous application commit means that hg absorb will never encounter merge conflicts!
>
> Now, you may be thinking if you ignore lines with ambiguous application targets, the patch would always apply cleanly using a classical 3-way merge. This statement logically sounds correct. But it isn't: `hg absorb` can avoid merge conflicts when the merging performed by `hg histedit` or `git rebase -i` would fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think `chistedit` (built in since Mercurial 2.3) is the closest to `rebase -i` that is pure Mercurial (`chistedit` is the interactive version of `histedit`). Once in histedit the `fold` command maps to rebase's `squash` and `roll` command maps to rebase's `fixup`. See [histedit](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension%20histedit) docs for more info.

Here is a simple example. Assume you have the following and want to move all 1e21c4b1's changes into the previous revision and just keeping the previous revision's message.

```
@  1e21c4b1 drees tip
|  A commit you want to squash
o  b4a738a4 drees
|  A commit
o  788aa028 drees
|  Older stuff
```

You can run `hg chistedit -r b4a738a4` to edit history back to b4a738a4. In chistedit you then cursor down to 1e21c4b1 and hit `r` to indicate you want to roll that revision. Do note that the order in histedit (oldest to newest) is reversed from `hg log` (newest to oldest).

```
#0  pick   160:b4a738a49916   A commit
#1  ^roll  161:1e21c4b1500c
```

After choosing your changes, you then choose `c` to commit them. The result is the following:

@  bfa4a3be drees tip
|  A commit
o  788aa028 drees
|  Older stuff

If you are relatively new to them, then `histedit` can be a better choice than `chistedit` because it provides the command descriptions in histedit file for reference. It just takes a bit more editing to set the commands using normal text editing (just like normal rebase).

Note, to use either `histedit` or `chistedit` you need to add `histedit` to your extensions in your ~/.hgrc:

```
[extensions]
histedit =
```

I suggested `chistedit` since it is closest to `rebase -i` and works anywhere in the history. If you really just want subsume/tweak the current revision into the previous one then  @G. Demecki's `strip` suggestion can be good since what is happening is clear. It is built in since Mercuria 2.8. To get the equivalent results as above you can do the following:

```
hg strip .
hg add
hg commit --amend
```

Note `strip`, like histedit, needs to be enabled in your ~/.hgrc:

```
[extensions]
strip =
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to squash (unite) 2 most recent commits.

1. Find a revision number

   ```
   hg log -G -l 3
   ```

   possible output:

   ```
   @  changeset:   156:a922d923cf6f
   |  branch:      default
   |  tag:         tip
   |  user:        naXa!
   |  date:        Thu Dec 13 15:45:58 2018 +0300
   |  summary:     commit message 3
   |
   o  changeset:   155:5feb73422486
   |  branch:      default
   |  user:        naXa!
   |  date:        Thu Dec 13 15:22:15 2018 +0300
   |  summary:     commit message 2
   |
   o  changeset:   154:2e490482bd75
   |  branch:      default
   ~  user:        naXa!
      date:        Thu Dec 13 03:28:27 2018 +0300
      summary:     commit message 1
   ```
2. Soft reset branch

   ```
   hg strip --keep -r 155
   ```
3. Commit changes again

   ```
   hg commit -m "new commit message"
   ```

#### Notes

`strip` requires a built-in extension to be enabled. Create/edit `~/.hgrc` config file with the following content:

```
[extensions]
strip =
```

Answer (score -2):

I use:

```
hg phase --draft --force -r 267
...
hg rebase --dest 282 --source 267 --collapse
```

Comment: downvoting because you just give the command without explaining