# Why does a merge need you to consider the common ancestor?

Tags: git, diff, three-way-merge

I'm learning Git, and am finding the tutorial on [this site](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/git-3.shtml) very useful.  On that page, concerning merging, it includes:

> ```
>          +---------- (D) ---------------+
>         /             |                  \
> (A) -- (B) -- (C) -------------- (E) -- (F)
>                       |                  |
>                  fix-headers           master
>                                          |
>                                         HEAD
> ```
>
> The merge commit is (F), having
>   parents (D) and (E). Because (B) is
>   the common ancestor between (D) and
>   (E), the files in (F) should contain
>   the changes between (B) and (D),
>   namely the heading fixes, incorporated
>   into the files from (E).

I don't understand why you would worry about the common ancestor B.  Why can't you just merge D and E to produce F?   D will have been derived from B but might contain differences you want.  There might have been a number of commits between B and D, with changes being made and taken out.

Comment: git uses changesets just like mercurial, so a Node only contains the difference to its parent.

Comment: @sleeplessnerd Actually, Git stores complete files, not diffs. Unless you meant something else by that?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/11343) for the advantages of 3-way merge

Comment: You're wrong sleeplessnerd. Each commit in git points to a complete snapshot of the entire project. If a certain file is different, a separate snapshot of the new version is stored rather than just the diffs. Mercurial OTOH uses delta storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because merging works better if you know the common ancestor. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129049/why-is-a-3-way-merge-advantageous-over-a-2-way-merge/4129145#4129145), it has good explanation why.

Answer (score 5):

*(I hesitate to ask if this is an April Fool's, I don't want to insult anyone...)*

Maybe you're not understanding that this is git doing the merge **for** you?

*Question*: Here are D and E, can you tell me what F should look like?

```
D                                        E
using System;                            using System;
public void main()                       public void main()
{                                        {
     Console.WriteLine("hello world");        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}                                        }
```

*Answer*: No, you can't

However, if you know that B looked like this:

```
B
using System;
public void main()
{
     Console.WriteLine("hello world");
}
```

It becomes a no brainer, and **git can handle this on its own**.

Dunno if that answers your question...

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a [good introduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28revision_control%29) on 3-way merge