# How can I see a "three way diff" for a Git merge conflict?

Tags: git

Suppose I'm on Git branch `master` and I `git merge featurebranch`. There is a conflict in `foo.html`.

When I open `foo.html`, I see, in the area of the conflict, what `master` has and what `featurebranch` has. But I can't really tell **what change** was made on `master` that conflicted with `featurebranch`; I only know what master has **now**.

I'd like to see the **diff** that each one applied.

Or, to get the same information, I could see:

- The version `master` has now
- The version `featurebranch` has now
- The version **their common ancestor** had

How can I see this?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

From [git-merge(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html),

> An alternative style can be used by setting the "merge.conflictstyle" configuration variable to "diff3".
>
> In addition to the `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>>` markers, it uses another `|||||||` marker that is followed by the original text. ... You can sometimes come up with a better resolution by viewing the original.

This can be enabled using

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

or right in `~/.gitconfig`file

```
[merge]
  conflictstyle = diff3
```

Comment: That is fantastic! Thank you! In the meantime I had discovered `git mergetool`, which (for me) opens `vimdiff` with several windows showing similar info, but I like your method better.

Comment: @NathanLong: btw, `mergetool` is really nice when using `kdiff3`

Comment: Also, if you just want to use this option for a single merge, without changing project-level or global configs: `git -c merge.conflictstyle=diff3 merge some_branch_name`

Answer (score 11):

A lot of GUI diff/merge tools have a 3 or 4 way merge view. I highly recommend [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) for resolving merge conflicts. Another (okay) tool is [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/).

You can set up a custom mergetool to use with the [`git mergetool`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html) command. This is my `.gitconfig` configuration for Beyond Compare (Pro edition) and DiffMerge on my Windows machine using msysgit:

```
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "dm"]
    cmd = C:/Program\\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = "\"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
[mergetool "bc3"]
    cmd = "\"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\""
```

You can read more about various diff/merge tool configurations in the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

Comment: +1 for Beyond Compare! I've used the Pro Edition for years and love it. Their support is also excellent.

Comment: The 3-way merge screenshot for Beyond Compare has the same window layout as I got in `vimdiff`.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate an explanation for any downvotes to this answer. Considering that I provide working configurations for some [popular external diff and merge tools](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/11/in-praise-of-beyond-compare.html) for msysgit installations on Windows, I think my answer provides great value.

Comment: For other's that got here and have been wondering why the above config doesn't work for 3-way merges, check that you have a Pro version of Beyond Compare and not a Standard license (which doesn't support 3-way-merge)

Comment: Thanks @nivekastoreth. It was doing a 2-way merge for me, no matter what I did. I was confused by the [Standard vs Pro](http://scootersoftware.com/shop.php?zz=kb_editions) page and mistakenly thought Starndard included 3-way file merges, but not directories. Upgrading to pro and [following directions](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitlinux) instantly fixed it up.

Comment: I ran into this issue again, and thought maybe it was a bug in BC where it forgot my license or something (even though Help>About shows my Pro license). When I did `git mergetool`, it showed only the `LOCAL` and `REMOTE` and not the `BASE` in BC. I don't understand why, but it turns out that BC indeed had a 3rd/middle column, but it wasn't showing it because the filename was blank. I think it was blank because the BASE file that should have been there had a 0 file size.

Comment: I feel like this answer was only a promote to Beyond Compare which btw is not so good