# Use three way diff for diff

Tags: git

Another [S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18131515/2547229) shows how to configure `git` to use a three way diff for merge conflicts.

Is it possible to set up this three way style as the default for a standard diff operation? If I request a diff between versions where there is a common root (that isn't just one of the versions), changes from the common root will be shown in the diff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is no.

The ratonale for this is that no matter how you specify the arguments when calling `git diff`, it always considers just two entities (blobs or trees (most of the time inferred from the commits referring to them)).

In other words, that's by design: `git diff` considers separate objects and does not do any history traversal. To cite the `git diff` manual page:

> For a more complete list of ways to spell `<commit>`, see "SPECIFYING REVISIONS"
> section in `gitrevisions(7)`. However, "diff" is about comparing two *endpoints,*
> not ranges, and the range notations ("`<commit>..<commit>`" and
> "`<commit>...<commit>`") do not mean a range as defined in the "SPECIFYING RANGES"
> section in `gitrevisions(7)`.

On the other hand, with a suitable shell, you should be able to do that thing yourself. Say, given two commits, `rev1` and `rev2`, you could use

```
git-diff3() {
  local rev1="$1" rev2="$2"
  diff3 <(git show "$rev1") \
        <(git show $(git merge-base "$rev1" "$rev2")) \
        <(git show "$rev2")
}
```

in a shell which understands `<(...)` (e.g. `bash`).

This function requires massaging to make it more useful/less fragile.

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer. I may give that a try.