# Programmatically display all git rerere resolutions used during merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff, git-rerere

When doing a merge with rerere enabled, and all conflicts are resolved with rerere,  it just prints something like:

```
Resolved 'a.c' using previous resolution.
Resolved 'b.c' using previous resolution.
Resolved 'c.c' using previous resolution.
```

I would like to see the before diff (with conflict markers) and after resolution diff. I know I can do:

```
git checkout -m a.c
git diff
git rerere
git diff
git checkout -m b.c
git diff
git rerere
git diff
...
```

to kind of see the pre/post images it's using for each resolution. But is there some way to retrieve that information, or the rerere fingerprints used, without manually parsing the `git merge hash` output for each `Resolved X using previous resolution.` message.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you're looking to compare *ours*, *theirs* and *resolution*. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440597/use-three-way-diff-for-diff) it seems that `git diff` will refuse to compare 3 files. I've amended the example from that post to provide this example;

```
git diff --name-only master feature |\
    xargs -I % bash -c "diff3 <( git show master:% ) <( cat % ) <( git show feature:% )"
```

The output from diff3 is more complicated but it's a complicated thing that you're doing.

## Replication Steps

Initialise the repo.

```
Horba@cake ~ $ git init MergeDiff/
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/Horba/MergeDiff/.git/
Horba@cake ~ $ cd MergeDiff/
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ vim README.md
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git add README.md 
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git commit -m "Init."
[master (root-commit) 5250b3f] Init.
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README.md
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git branch feature
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git config rerere.enabled true
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git config rerere.autoupdate true
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ vim README.md 
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git add README.md
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git commit -m "Work on master."
[master 8c12c43] Work on master.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git checkout feature
Switched to branch 'feature'
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ vim README.md
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git commit -m "Work on feature."
[feature 4b8ad3d] Work on feature.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Conduct the initial merge.

```
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git merge feature 
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md
Recorded preimage for 'README.md'
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ cat README.md
# MergeDiff

<<<<<<< HEAD
Init - master changes
=======
Init - Work on feature
>>>>>>> feature
```

Store a resolution.

```
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ vim README.md
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git rerere
Recorded resolution for 'README.md'.
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ cat README.md
# MergeDiff

Init - Resolved
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git merge --abort
```

Merge again using rerere.autoupdate.

```
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git merge feature 
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md
Staged 'README.md' using previous resolution.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ cat README.md
# MergeDiff

Init - Resolved
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   README.md
```

Traditional diff doesn't help.

```
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ git diff feature master HEAD
diff --cc README.md
index ca2c305,ca2c305..24b898d
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@@ -1,3 -1,3 +1,3 @@@
  # MergeDiff

--Init - master changes
++Init - Work on feature
```

`diff3` can do it.

```
Horba@cake ~/MergeDiff $ diff3 <(git show master:README.md) <(git show feature:README.md) <( cat README.md )
====1
1:1,3c
  # MergeDiff

  Init - master changes
2:0a
3:0a
====2
1:6c
3:3c
  Init - Resolved
2:3c
  Init - Work on feature
```

Answer (score 1):

The postimage and preimage are stored in `.git/rr-cache/$hex`. After the auto-merge is done, we have a file whose content is the same with the postimage.

Here is a quick and dirty bash function to print the preimage of X, or the diff between HEAD's version and the preimage. A side effect is that dangling blobs will be created.

```
# input: file path
# output: the preimage with conflict markers, 
#         or the diff between HEAD's version and the preimage. 
#         If the file path does not exist in rerere cache, return nothing.
function foo(){
    p=$1
    current=`git hash-object $p`
    for hex in `ls .git/rr-cache`;do
        posthash=`git hash-object .git/rr-cache/$hex/postimage`
        if [ "$posthash" = "$current" ];then
            git diff HEAD:$p $(git hash-object -w .git/rr-cache/$hex/preimage)
            # To print the preimage
            #cat .git/rr-cache/$hex/preimage
            return
        fi
    done
}

foo a.c
```