# changes from what file get picked when two files are merged

Tags: git, merge

For instance I have a history like this

```
A -> B -> C -> F -> G ---------- feature
           \
            D -> E  -------- master
```

Throughout the history I have a file *a.txt* with the first line in it, say, "sometext".
On commit **G** I decide to remove "sometext" and leave the first line blank. Then I merge these two branches. A new commit is formed with the first line being blank. So **E** contains "sometext" line and **G** does not. So this is a difference between branches that are being merged. How does git decide what to include in merge commit? Is it because **G** was made after **E** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it will identify the common ancestor `C` of both branches, and compare the changes since that ancestor on each branch `C..G` vs `C..E`.

Since `C..E` doesn't touch the line, but `C..G` does, `G`'s change is taken. If *both* branches changed the same line in different ways, it would ask you to resolve the conflict manually.

This is a [3-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28revision_control%29#Three-way_merge): see [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/212858) for some discussion, and the [Merge Strategies](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) section in the documentation for more merge options.