# How GIT understands it can get newest file and not show it in diff

Tags: git, pull-request

let's say we create a branch `new_branch`. We change 1 file there, commit this one file, push and create a pull request to `parent rep/master`.

meanwhile parent rep changed quite a bit, let's say 100 files were changed but that 1 file wasn't touched.

And still, pull request diff will show that only 1 file was changed.

So how `GIT` understands that actually 1 file needs to be merged only, and not 101 files. I mean `parent rep/master` compare to `child rep/new_branch` in fact 101 files were changed and not 1 file..

Comment: You're basically asking "how does a version control system work", the answer to which is quite broad... But all git needs to do is follow the history of `new_branch` to see what has been changed in that branch since it last branched off the main tree. And that is only 1 file.

Comment: Just a hunch, but I think what you're interested in is merging. You want to merge the changes from master into your main branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a three-way merge, which means git will compare your evolution against the common ancestor between:

- your branch
- the parentRepo branch

That difference is the one applied for the merge.

See more at "[Why is a 3-way merge advantageous over a 2-way merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/6309)".

```
A----C  (yourBranch: 1 file modified, compared to A, the common ancestor)
 \
  --B   (parentRepo master: 100 files modified)
```

When merging:

```
A----C  
 \    \
  --B--D (only one file is merged to parentRepo branch)
```

See more at "[Pro Git book: Basic Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merging)":

[image: http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0316-tn.png]