# What's the difference between vimdiff and vimdiff2 in git?

Tags: git, vim, vimdiff

What's the difference between them? My search engine results talk only about vimdiff, yet the command

```
git mergetool
```

offers me both.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`vimdiff2` was introduced in [commit 0008669](https://github.com/git/git/commit/000866909a5d9233c89d8fcc33a8125cc84f24d6) (Sept 2010, for git 1.7.4)

It is [like vimdiff](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/mergetools/vimdiff2), but with different merge options (as commented in [commit b2a6b71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2a6b7122e66d4882ef5ac31e3a03969b5b6a199), git 1.8.2: "vimdiff and vimdiff2 differ only by their merge command").

It (`vimdiff2`) forces a 2-way merge, versus `vimdiff` which will use a **[3-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130766/6309)** if the base (common ancestor) is detected:

```
gvimdiff|vimdiff)
    if $base_present
    then
        "$merge_tool_path" -f -d -c 'wincmd J' \
            "$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"
    else
        "$merge_tool_path" -f -d -c 'wincmd l' \
            "$LOCAL" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE"
    fi
    ;;
gvimdiff2|vimdiff2)
    "$merge_tool_path" -f -d -c 'wincmd l' \
        "$LOCAL" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE"
    ;;
```

Note that [commit 7c147b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c147b77d34f072c40b912fafba499727921fa6e) (April 2014, for Git 2.1.0 August 2014) actually introduces `vimdiff3` as well:

> It's similar to the default, except that the other windows are hidden.
>   This ensures that removed/added colors are still visible on the main merge window, but the other windows not visible.
>
> Specially useful with `merge.conflictstyle=diff3`.

Comment: What would you recommend for resolving merge conflicts?

"Unfortunately Vim struggles a bit with three-way diffs, both with highlighting the differences and with shuffling individual changes between the three windows." Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/A_better_Vimdiff_Git_mergetool

Comment: @nomadStack indeed. I prefer to use kdiff3.