# How can I retrospectively merge a git branch?

Tags: git

*Note* this is not a duplicate as flagged - it turned out I *didn't* want to `cherry-pick`, but `merge`. As such, I feel it should be regarded as its own question in case others encounter the same situation.

---

I have a `develop` branch that contains a series of commits. I regularly merge this branch back into `master` when the feature set is complete. At some point in the past, I realise I should have merged the `develop` branch. For example:

```
A
 \     Merge
  \      |
   B--C--D--E--F
```

`A` is the last commit on `master`, `B` is the first commit of the `develop` branch.

I wish to merge commits `B`, `C` and `D` into `master`, but I only know how to merge whole branch. Eventually, commits `E` and `F` will get merged in, but right now I need to just merge up to `D`.

```
A----------D
 \        /
  \      /
   B--C--D--E--F
```

I know I can do the following for a single commit, but how can I do a range?

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick B
```

*Note to future self*: remember to always create a feature branch!

Comment: on the top of my head, can you just do `git merge D`, issued from master?

Comment: Does that merge all commits before `D`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a quick comment regarding cherry-pick: cherry-pick and merge are very different (more on that in a bit).

#### Merging a specific commit

Now, on to merge.  Typically we describe the merge sequence like this:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge sidebranch
```

If the automatic merge goes well, git will create a new *merge commit* on the current branch—in this case, on `master`—whose everyday "first" parent is the previous tip of the current branch, and whose *second* parent is the commit we told git to merge.

The fact that there *is* a second parent is what makes this a merge commit.  Diagrammatically we get:

```
A <----------- M  <-- master
 \           /
  B <- C <- D     <-- sidebranch
```

where `M` has as its two parents `A` and `D`.  The name `master` now points to the new merge commit `M`, while the name `sidebranch` is untouched and still points to `D`.

What `git merge` does with the `sidebranch` argument is two things, only one of which really matters:

- it translates it to a specific commit and merges using that commit; and
- it puts the argument name into the default commit message (`merge branch sidebranch` or `merge branch sidebranch into foo` where `into foo` appears only if the current branch is *not* named `master`).

The second item does not really matter, at least not to git: git only shows you that commit message, it never depends on the message.  If you choose to edit the message you can make it say something else.

The point of all this is that you can identify *any* commit, not just the tip of a branch, and git can merge that.  So if `sidebranch` keeps going, as in your case, but you specify commit `D` specifically, you get:

```
A <----------- M          <-- master
 \           /
  B <- C <- D <- E <- F   <-- sidebranch
```

which is what you want.  Git's auto-generated merge commit message text, however, says `merge commit <hash>`, which is probably *not* what you want.  That's easy to fix: just edit it to read `merge branch sidebranch`.

(To accomplish the merge itself, git does the usual [three-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/1256452), finding the merge base and diffing that commit against the two commits that are to be merged.)

#### The rest of the side note on cherry-pick

The key difference between merge and cherry-pick is not so much the merging itself (you can cherry-pick a range of commits, and even do so without committing each one by adding `-n` to the cherry-pick command: the result is what git calls a "squash merge", except much less efficient and you might have to resolve the same conflicts many times this way).  Rather, it's that the final commit is *not a merge commit*, i.e., does not have a second parent.

This means that the resulting commit *graph* is different, even if the source code changes are the same (as they are for a squash "merge").  This has no *immediate* effect, but it means a *future* merge won't know that the cherry-pick already happened, and will have to work hard to skip it (this may or may not succeed).  Recording the second parent gives git all the information it needs to locate the correct new merge base for the later merge.

As an example, consider the squash-"merge" you get by copying the effect of `B+C+D` onto `master`:

```
A <-------- S             <-- master
 \
  B <- C <- D <- E <- F   <-- sidebranch
```

Here `S` is produced by taking "what we did in `B`" (by diffing `A` vs `B`) and applying that to the source tree for `A`, then taking "what we did in `C`" (diff `B` vs `C`) and applying that, and last, taking "what we did in `D`" and applying that.  Everything is fine so far—what we did in `B` clearly must apply cleanly to `A`, and so on.

The problem occurs when (or maybe "if") we later go to merge `sidebranch` into `master` again.  Git will search for the merge-base and find that it is commit `A`, so it will compare `A` vs `S`, and `A` vs `F`.  It *may* then be able to automatically construct the right tree, depending on the changes in `E` and `F` vs the changes we cherry-picked earlier.  If we had merged, though, git would see `D` as the merge base, and compare `D`-vs-`F` to get new items to bring into `master`.

Comment: Wow. I cannot thank you enough for this detailed answer. Sincere thanks for not only answering the question, but informing me _italic_ why I should be merging instead of `cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick b^..d
```

Git 1.7.2 introduced the ability to cherrypick a range of commits.

> git cherry-pick" learned to pick a range of commits (e.g. "cherry-pick A..B" and "cherry-pick --stdin"), so did "git revert"; these do not support the nicer sequencing control "rebase [-i]" has, though.

Comment: it's possible, but you shouldn't really do cherry-picking in the case described by OP. The other answer has details as to why not.