# Git: Why is a merge-base necessary

Tags: git, svn, merge, branch

I know Git doesn't save diffs in the repository (as SVN does). Instead it saves a new tree-object for each commit and new blob-objects for every file that has changed.
So, when merging two branches, why is it not enough to merge only both branch-heads?
Why must a merge-base be found to apply all the intermediate steps within a merge?

Thx very much for each answer.

Comment: How exactly would you merge two snapshots? See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/1256452

Comment: Thx very much. This solved my problem;)