# Why do I get conflicts after a git revert in this special case

Tags: git

I have a file that in the beginning looked like this

```
asd
bnm
cvb
```

Then I added three commits:

1.

```
asd feature1 c1
bnm
cvb
```

2.

```
asd feature1 c1
bnm feature1 c2
cvb
```

3.

```
asd feature1 c1
bnm feature1 c2
cvb feature1 c3
```

Now when I want to revert commit number two by doing

```
git revert HEAD^
```

I get an error message like this

```
error: could not revert 2222222... feature 1 commit 2
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

and my file looks like this

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
bnm feature1 c2
cvb feature1 c3
=======
bnm
cvb
\>>>>>>> parent of 2222222... feature 1 commit 2
```

And I just don't understand why. My assumption is that it would work like Edwar Thomson explains it in his answer to this question:
[git revert: Why do I get conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275070/git-revert-why-do-i-get-conflicts)
I didn't edit line 2 twice and should not get a conflict. What am I missing?

I expect the result to be

```
asd feature1 c1
bnm
cvb feature1 c3
```

without any conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is missing here is that a revert, like a cherry-pick, is only applying a patch (here the negative image of a past commit).
It is not merging.

That means, as I described in "[Git cherry-pick causes merge conflict while merging does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37238212/6309)", it has no notion of common ancestor.

The problem is the context of the patch computed by a git revert: see "[Conflicts from apply and stash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47146424/6309)".

The revert (negative diff between 2 and 1) tries to cancel line 2 (reverting `bnm feature1 c2` to `bnm`, *before* a third line `cvb`) on a HEAD content which has *not* cvb as a third line.
When applying that patch, Git doesn't know what to do with the third line: should it leave it alone, or modify it to `cvb`.

See another example in "[Why does this cherry-pick have a conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38989749/6309)".

Comment: Interesting answer, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37151159 revert *does* use a 3-way merge. To verify that the conflict occurs when there is a common ancestor, check out a new branch pointing at commit 2, revert commit 2, then merge this new branch into commit 3 (it should conflict).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the link provided: 'Git cherry-pick causes merge conflict while merging does not' It's pointing to ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063296/cant-change-username-and-password-from-git/33063731#33063731 '  Is this intended?

Comment: No, probably a typo, I will fix the link when I go back

Comment: Technically both revert and cherry-pick use the parent of the commit being picked or reverted as the common ancestor when running the 3-way merge. There is a way to apply a commit as "pure patch" (rather than merge), using `git apply`, and you can do forward or reverse here. If you have an `index` with blob hashes, and use `-3`, the apply will *fall back* to doing a 3-way merge if the straightforward "apply patch" part fails.