# Is there any way to directly checkout "both modified" or "unmerged paths" files of git?

Tags: git

I know there is a long way to checkout both modified files by following commands.

```
git add <filename>
git reset HEAD <filename>
git checkout <filename>
```

But is there one single command which can checkout all the "unmerged paths"?

Comment: Are you asking this question in the context of a merge conflict?

Comment: Yeah. And the changes in the conflicted files deemed unnecessary to me, so I want to get rid of them at one go.

Comment: Which parent's version do you want to keep here?

Comment: "theirs". The ones residing in the origin branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence of commands you listed will *not* produce the `--theirs` version.  Instead, it produces, in both the work-tree and the index, the `--ours` version.  There are several ways to achieve this with fewer commands, and for multiple path names.

The second shorted method is perhaps the one you should use:

```
git checkout --ours path1 path2 ... pathN
```

or:

```
git checkout --theirs path1 path2 ... pathN
```

followed by `git add` of those same paths.  *Be very sure that it is OK to throw out their or your changes with respect to the merge base!*  Pay particular attention to which commit *is* the merge base, so that you know what you are keeping and what you are throwing out.

To make this one step shorter, you can use `git checkout HEAD` or `git checkout MERGE_HEAD` and skip the `git add` step; but see below.

---

The key thing to understand here is that whenever Git detects conflicts, Git stores *all three* versions of the file in the index.  In this situation, you can access any or all of these three versions.  This is, for instance, how `git mergetool` obtains the versions it calls BASE, LOCAL, and REMOTE, which Git more generally calls the *merge base*, the `HEAD` or `--ours` version, and the other or `--theirs` version.

Remember that the index is the place where Git keeps a copy of each file that will go into the next commit you make.  (Git calls this the *index*, or the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*, depending on which part of Git documentation is doing the calling.)  In normal operation, there is only one copy of any such file.  That is, if you have a file named `README.txt` that was in the commit you checked out and is in the work-tree that you can work on, you also have a copy of this same `README.txt` in the index.

The copy in the work-tree is an ordinary file, in the same format as any normal file on your computer.  The committed copy, stored in the `HEAD` commit, is in a special, Git-only format, where it is not only compressed but also entirely *read-only:* the committed copy can never be changed.  You can, of course, make a *new and different* commit that has a different version of `README.txt`, but the way you do that is by first copying that new and different `README.txt` into the index.

Note that at any time, you can view the copy in the `HEAD` commit with `git show HEAD:README.txt`.  Similarly, you can view the copy in the index with `git show :README.txt`, where the leading colon is special Git syntax for *a file from the index*.

Typically you copy a new version into the index via `git add README.txt`, which simply takes whatever is in the work-tree right now and copies it into the index / staging-area, overwriting the (single) previous copy.  But when you hit a merge conflict during `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` or `git revert` or `git stash apply` or any other operation that performs the *to merge* action—what I like to call *merge as a verb*—the index takes on a new role.

While the index normally holds just *one* copy of `README.txt`, during a conflicted merge, the index holds (up to) *three* copies of `README.txt`.  Remember that a merge works by comparing your version of the file—your `README.txt`—to some *merge base* version of that same file, and then also by comparing *their* version of `README.txt` to that *same merge base version*.  By making these two separate comparisons, Git can figure out what *you* changed, and what *they* changed.  Git then combines these two sets of changes, applying *both* sets to the *merge base* version of the file.  See also [VonC's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130766/1256452).

If Git is not able to combine both sets of changes on its own, what Git does at this point is to use what it calls *stage slots* in the index.  Rather than just the one `README.txt` in the index, Git can store up to *four* versions.  However, it uses at most three, and it numbers them:

- Staging slot zero holds the unconflicted `:README.txt`.
- Staging slot #1 holds the *merge base* `1:README.txt`.
- Staging slot #2 holds the *ours* version `2:README.txt`.
- Staging slot #3 holds the *theirs* version `:3:README.txt`.

When `git status`, with or without `--short`, shows you *unmerged files*, what it means is that there are entries in staging slots 1, 2, and 3.  In this case slot zero is *not used!*

Git writes the conflicted copy of `README.txt` to the work-tree, so that you can look at the conflicts and resolve it yourself, but it also stores *all three inputs* in the index.  You can check any one of them out, but slots 2 and 3 have a syntax to make it easy:

```
git checkout --ours README.txt
```

extracts from slot 2, while:

```
git checkout --theirs README.txt
```

extracts from slot 3.  All three versions remain in the index, but now the work-tree holds either ours (the `HEAD` version) or theirs (the `MERGE_HEAD` version).

Running `git add` takes *whatever is in the work-tree right now*, even if it still has merge conflicts in it, and *writes that to slot zero, wiping out slots 1 through 3.*  This causes Git to believe that the conflict is resolved.

You can of course check out, or add, more than one file name at a time, so you can use:

```
git status --porcelain | grep '^UU ' | cut -f2-
```

to generate the list of all unmerged files (their short status is `UU`), and use that to make a list of files to extract.  This method is not very robust (fails in the presence of files with funny characters or spaces in their names) but suffices for simple cases:

```
files=$(git status --porcelain | grep '^UU ' | cut -f2-)
git checkout --theirs $files
git add $files
```

#### Removing one step

To shorten all of this one step, we can make use of a peculiar fact about `git checkout`.  Using `git checkout --ours path` or `git checkout --theirs path` has Git extract a file from the index (in its Git-only format there) to the work-tree (in normal format), which does not change anything in the index itself.  But using `git checkout tree-ish path` has Git extract a file from a *commit*, not from the index.  When Git does this, it first copies that file *into* the index.  Only after the file is in the index does `git checkout` copy the file to the work-tree.

Copying a file into the index has the side effect of deleting any stage 1, 2, and 3 slot copies of the file, writing the file to staging slot zero.  So if the file was previously unmerged, it has suddenly become merged.

Note that if we are in a conflicted merge, the hash ID of the commit we are merging is stored in `MERGE_HEAD`.  If we are in the middle of a cherry-pick, the hash ID of the commit we are picking is in `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`.  (See the other commands for where they store their hash IDs.)

Hence, even though the copy that is in staging slot 2 came from the `HEAD` commit, and the copy in staging slot 3 came from `MERGE_HEAD`, if we deliberately extract a file from `HEAD` or `MERGE_HEAD` into the index and then into the work-tree, this writes the file to staging slot zero.  The effect is to resolve the merge while also choosing our (`HEAD`) or their (`MERGE_HEAD`) version of the file.

Thus, for files that do not have difficult names, the command:

```
git checkout HEAD $(git status --porcelain | grep '^UU ' | cut -f2-)
```

does the trick to choose `--ours`, while:

```
git checkout MERGE_HEAD $(git status --porcelain | grep '^UU ' | cut -f2-)
```

does the trick to choose `--theirs` for `git merge` (only!).  *Again, do not use this unless you know exactly what you are doing.*