# VS Code v1.70 merge editor UI changed. How to revert?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Up until now, I found VS Code merge editor extremely useful and developer friendly. It had:

- Green highlighting for `Current Changes`.
- Blue highlighting for `Incoming Changes`.
- Inline buttons for `Accept Current Change`, `Accept Incoming Change`, `Accept Both Changes`, `Compare Changes`.

Today after updating to v1.70, when I tried to resolve some conflicts, the merge editor UI changed completely (probably because of new version of VS Code). I would prefer to keep the old merge editor UI. Can this be solved with some VS Code config?

Comment: Why would you ever NOT [want to use a proper 3-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/23118)? You really, really need to invest a tiny bit of time understanding what a 3-way merge is. It will be well invested time that you will get back multiple times. Proper 3-way merge is one of those thing that once you've started using you will never go back to using just 2-way.

Comment: @hlovdal Have you read the question? It's about the UI of the editor. UI has changed, not the actual features I think. Previously, you could resolve conflicts inline in one window. Now, it opens 3 different windows (for current changes, for incoming changes, and for final result). I just got used to resolving it inline in one window.

Comment: Despite what Microsoft claims for the new feature, what they have is NOT a proper 3-way merge, because that requires 4 windows/views not just 3. But my point still stands, a proper 3-way merge is superior to any of the two alternatives provided by vscode.

Answer (score 4):

I found solution in the official [June 2022 docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_3-way-merge-editor):

> In this release, we continued working on the 3-way merge editor. This
> feature can be enabled by setting git.mergeEditor to true and will be
> enabled by default in future releases.

It [became the default in v1.70](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_3way-merge-editor-improvements).

So, adding the following line in `settings.json` solved it:

```
"git.mergeEditor": false
```

Note: The default was [reverted back to the inline editor in v1.72](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_72#_merge-editor).