# Fold outgoing changesets into a single changeset in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I want to checkpoint/commit stages (locally) using mercurial, knowing well that these changes would break the build if I pushed them to the remote repository. What I would like to do is fold/collapse/accumulate these changesets into a single changeset that I can push. I do not want the the remote repository to have these intermediate checkpoints in its history. I would like all recorded versions on the remote repository to at least build properly.

Is there any simple way to do this, perhaps an extension. I would have assume that this would be a selling point of a DVCS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I squash commits in Mercurial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725607/can-i-squash-commits-in-mercurial)

Comment: +Ry4an upvoted your answer. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Another here http://stackoverflow.com/q/1200691/617371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Histedit](http://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension (**fold** command)

or

- [MQ](http://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension) extension (qimport + qfold + qfinish cycle) - "Combining entire patches" chapter in chapter [Managing change with Mercurial Queues](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html) of "Mercurial: The Definitive Guide"

Comment: Thanks. Also found this http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension now I have to find out which is the easiest to use. In case you have preference for one or the other I would like to know.