# Mercurial -- grab all files inside a repository, including subrepos, but not the repository itself

Tags: mercurial, changeset, fold, mercurial-subrepos

Is this possible?

To give a simplified explanation of what I want to do:

I have a repository "A" with a subrepository "B".  I have two copies of the pair.

In one copy (let's call it the small copy), "A" has changesets A1-A5, and "B" has changesets B1-B20.

In the other (big) copy, "A" has changesets A1-A10, and "B" has changesets B1-B30.

What I want to do is have take all the files from the big repo and commit them to the small one as changesets A6 and B21.  Then I will push that to the server.  (The big repo does not exist on the server, so this should not create any conflicts.).

Tools in this area do seem to exist -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200691/with-mercurial-how-can-i-compress-a-series-of-changesets-into-one-before-pushi), for example.  The problem is I don't know whether any of the suggested methods play nice with subrepositories.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use something like the [collapse extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension).

Alternately, next time you could use mercurial queues so that your A6-A10 are commits on a patch in a patch repo, which you can then qfinish and push as A6.  The suprepo existing shouldn't change either of those suggestions in any fundamental way.