# create a commit, save it, don;t push it than create some few more commits , push them than push the first commit

Tags: github, commit

What if I want to save a commit say `commit-1` but don;t want to push it and then after few commits,which I have pushed also, then I want to push that `commit-1` ?

Comment: Are you need to push bulk of commits?

Answer (score 0):

You want to reorder the local commits before pushing?

You can do that using `git rebase --interactive`. Be sure to read about the pitfalls of using this, though. Used correctly it is very powerful.