# Patch the move of an image on Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

In my project, I've an PNG file and I want to move it on another directory.
I've done

```
mv f.png foo/f.png
hg addremove
hg diff > patch.diff
```

But I get this in my patch :

```
diff -r f0a573ab03b1 Bundles/rc/f.png
Binary file Bundles/rc/f.png has changed
diff -r f0a573ab03b1 Bundles/media/rc/f.png
Binary file Bundles/media/rc/f.png has changed
```

So when I apply it, it doesn't work... Is there someone who can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use `hg mv` instead of `mv`. That way, Mercurial knows that you renamed the file. When you use `addremove`, you pollute your history with a file delete and then a file add.

The next problem is the patch. The patch format doesn't support binary files. There is no way to create a patch for images.

Try `hg export --git` instead of `hg diff`. See this question: [Why are my dlls not included in my exported patches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531807/why-are-my-dlls-not-included-in-my-exported-patches)

`hg export` and `hg import` know how to handle all kinds of corner cases (like preserving your commit messages).

Comment: Okay, so is there a way to patch just the modification of image's location ?

Comment: Try to rename the image using `hg mv`. Maybe it can encode that in a patch. If that doesn't work, you'll have to notify the other developers to move the file.

Comment: You can use `hg diff -g` or `hg export -g` to make `diff/export` use git's extended diff format, which does handle binaries, renames, etc. See `hg help diffs`. You can also set `git=true` in section `[diff]` of your `~/.hgrc` to get git-style diffs by default. Note that most patch tools do not understand the git extensions to the patch format, so make sure the recipient can use such a patch.