# Push as a single revision

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have 6 draft revisions, now i want to push all these to server, but as a single revision. i.e to public it should be visible as single revision.

I'm using TortoiseHg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of **[With Mercurial, how can I "compress" a series of changesets into one before pushing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200691/with-mercurial-how-can-i-compress-a-series-of-changesets-into-one-before-push)**

You will find all the different alternatives you can use. But since you are using TortoiseHg, I'd suggest you try the `Compress History...` function, also mentioned in the answers (right-click on both start-end revisions). This will create a new changeset containing all the changes in the multiple changesets selected. Then you can just strip the old draft changesets, and keep the new one only.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify history on push, you must collapse changesets by hand (MQ, hisedit) before it